# How to resize a java applet when the browser is resized?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, resize

I have a java applet that is embedded in html using the `object-comment-embed` method. I would like to resize the applet whenever the browser window is resized. I have found solutions around the internet, but they all work based on the deprecated `applet` tag.

Also, when trying a `setSize()` call on my `embed` element in FireBug, it will resize the content of the applet, but not the applet viewport. That is, the area of the display that is given over to java does not change.

Current code looks something like this:

```
<object
    id='MyApplet1'
    width='300' height='200'
    classid='clsid:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    codebase='http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,6,0,0'>
    <param name='type' value='application/x-java-applet;version=1.6'>
    <param name='scriptable' value='false'>
    <param name='codebase' value='foo'>
    <param name='code' value='bar'>
    <param name='archive' value='baz'>
    <param name='arg1' value='A'>
    <param name='arg2' value='B'>
    <comment>
        <embed
            id='MyApplet2'
            width='300' height='200'
            pluginspage='http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download'
            type='application/x-java-applet;version=1.6'
            scriptable='false'
            codebase='foo'
            code='bar'
            archive='baz'
            arg1='A'
            arg2='B'>
            <noembed>
            </noembed>
        </embed>
    </comment>
</object>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function resize() {
  min_width = 300;
  min_height = 200;
  frame_width = 0;
  frame_height = 0;
  if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion) > 3) {
    if(navigator.appName=='Netscape') {
      frame_width = window.innerWidth;
      frame_height = window.innerHeight;
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft') != -1) {
      frame_width = document.body.offsetWidth;
      frame_height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
  }
  frame_width *= 0.78;
  frame_height *= 0.78;
  applet_width = frame_width > min_width ? frame_width : min_width;
  applet_height = frame_height > min_height ? frame_height : min_height;
  document.getElementById('MyApplet1').setSize(applet_width, applet_height);
  document.getElementById('MyApplet2').setSize(applet_width, applet_height);
}
window.onResize = resize;
window.onLoad = resize;
</script>
```

Comment: does your resize function get called? (e.g. where is the error so far?)

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing these lines:

```
document.getElementById('MyApplet1').setSize(applet_width, applet_height);
document.getElementById('MyApplet2').setSize(applet_width, applet_height);
```

with:

```
document.getElementById('MyApplet1').style.height = applet_height + "px";
document.getElementById('MyApplet1').style.width = applet_width + "px";

document.getElementById('MyApplet2').style.height = applet_height + "px";
document.getElementById('MyApplet2').style.width = applet_width + "px";
```

Comment: My vote is for this method. I've basically done this same thing to resize ActiveX controls. It should work the same for an Applet.

Comment: This worked!  I was doing the same thing, using setSize().  It was being called but the applet wasn't resizing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use percentage width and height. I usually use the following code for my applets:

```
<applet codebase="http://localhost:89" archive="npaxet?version=0.0.1.28" code="main.NPaxet.class" width=100% height=90%>\
<PARAM NAME="thumbnailUrl" VALUE="http://localhost:89/thumbnail?seriesid=%s">
<PARAM NAME="dicomUrl" VALUE="http://localhost:89/dicom?imageid=%d">
<PARAM NAME="seriesCount" VALUE="11">
...
</applet>
```